# Vertical and Horizontal Asymptotes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem:

> If
>   $$f(x) = \frac{2x-8}{x^2 -2x - 3} \qquad\text{ and }\qquad g(x) = \frac{3x+9}{2x-4}$$find the sum of the values of $x$ where the vertical asymptotes of $f(g(x))$ are located.

Follow-up Problem:

> What is the horizontal asymptote as $x$ approaches negative infinity of $f(g(x))$?

How would I do these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) = \frac{2x-8}{x^2 -2x - 3} \qquad\text{ and }\qquad g(x) = \frac{3x+9}{2x-4}$$

Then $$f(g(x)) = \frac{2\cdot \frac{3x+9}{2x-4}-8}{\left(\frac{3x+9}{2x-4}\right)^2-2\cdot \frac{3x+9}{2x-4}-3}$$

$$f(g(x))=\frac{\frac{6x+18-8(2x-4)}{2x-4}}{\frac{(3x+9)^2-2(3x+9)(2x-4)-3(2x-4)^2}{(2x-4)^2}}$$

$$\require{cancel}f(g(x)) = \frac{-10x+50}{\cancel{2x-4}}\cdot \frac{(2x-4)^{\cancel{2}}}{-15(x+1)(x-7)}$$

$$f(g(x)) = \frac{20(x-5)(x-2)}{15(x+1)(x-7)}=\frac{4(x-5)(x-2)}{3(x+1)(x-7)}$$

Can you see how to do it from here?

In case you get stuck:
The vertical asymptotes are given by $x=-1$ and $x=7$ (since these are the values for which the denominator is $0$), the sum of these is $6$

as $x\to -\infty, f(g(x))\to \frac{4}{3}\quad$ note you can see this by dividing top and bottom by $x^2$, and considering what happens as $x\to -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal asymptote of $f(g(x))$ as $x \to \infty$ is nothing else than $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} f(g(x))$

Since $$\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3x+9}{2x-4}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{3+\dfrac 9x}{2-\dfrac 4x}=\frac 32$$

Therefore ;

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(g(x))=\lim_{x \to \infty} f\left(\frac 32\right)=f\left(\frac 32\right)=\frac 43$$